# List webpart: change background color

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, json-formatting, background

When I use a list as a webpart the background is plain white (see white behind honeycomb icons and the light blue background of the site panel).

[image]

Is there a way to change the background of the whole list? When changing the individual list items it does not apply to the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to change background color of list web part.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.